# Bootstrap Modal: Left and right aligned content in modal footer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this modal:

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/482/

I have some buttons on the right, and text on the left. I want these to be aligned vertically. The text should be on the same line if you place a ruler under it. I can't seem to be able to do this.

Any ideas?

```
<div class="modal-footer" style="margin-top:0;">
    <div style="float:left;color:#737373;font-style:italic"><strong>test:</strong> - <a href="#">advanced</a></div>
    <div style="float:right">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Submitting...">Send Message</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

You could simply add the text in a `span` with 2 native bootstrap classes applied: `form-control-static` for vertically aligning the text with the buttons and `pull-left` for left aligning the text in the footer.

There's no need for the extra floating divs, the buttons will already be right aligned by the `modal-footer` class. You can even adjust text- and buttonsizes for example by applying `input-lg` and `btn-lg` classes to the span and buttons respectively:

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <span class="form-control-static pull-left">Example vertically aligned text</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just give the `div` in question the same line-height as your button height is.

In your case it would be `line-height: 34px;`.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/483/)