# Bootstrap 5 modal footer align left and right

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap5-modal

Can somebody help me with Bootstrap 5 modal footer?
I want to make a modal footer have a text (span or label) in the left and button in the right

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43271747) solution and try it (changed everyting from "left" to "start") but not working.
I tried using `d-flex justify-content-start` and also tried using `float-start` but still not working.

Comment: Show me your full code

Comment: @Jello here's the code https://www.codeply.com/p/EKSUKD50Is

Comment: You can also use a class like this: ```<div class="modal-footer justify-content-between"></div>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify some structure to achieve it.

CSS:

```
.modal-footer {
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#inputInv">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="inputInv" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="InputInventory" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="InputInventory">INPUT DATA</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- CONTENT HERE -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div>
                    <span>Example vertically aligned text</span>
                </div>
                <div class="actions">
                    <button id="btnInClose" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button id="btnInSave" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Save</button> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check [this](https://codepen.io/guswnsxodlf/pen/zYEMKMY) for the example.

Answer (score 7):

Simply use the `justify-content-between` class on the modal-footer...

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="inputInv" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="InputInventory" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="InputInventory">INPUT DATA</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- CONTENT HERE -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                <div>
                    <span>Example vertically aligned text</span>
                </div>
                <div class="actions">
                    <button id="btnInClose" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button id="btnInSave" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Save</button> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Updated Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/0OeTCmNMyd)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Bootstrap-5 then don't need to write CSS for `text` or element alignment so you need to use pre-defined classes from *BS-5*.
You just need to add `me-auto` class in `<span>` or `<label>` then text will render from **left side**.

*Helpful like:* 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/
https://css-tricks.com/how-auto-margins-work-in-flexbox/

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-5" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <span class="me-auto">Example vertically aligned text</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#inputInv">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="inputInv" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="InputInventory" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="InputInventory">INPUT DATA</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- CONTENT HERE -->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="flex-grow-1 bd-highlight">Example vertically aligned text</div>
        <div class="bd-highlight"><button id="btnInClose" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>
        <div class="bd-highlight"><button id="btnInSave" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Save</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think This would fix your problem
Just added the buttons and the text into the div elements and added class `bd-highlight` to the three div elements
Also added class `flex-grow-1` to the text div element